# how to make a join using the repository pattern and ADO .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, ado.net

I would like to know the best way to make a join with ado.net using a repository pattern.

Exemple :

```
public class PostRepository : BaseRepository<int, PostModel>
{
    private static PostRepository instance;

    public static PostRepository Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance ?? (instance = new PostRepository());
        }

    }

    private PostRepository() : base("Post")
    {
    }

    public override PostModel Convert(IDataRecord dataRecord)
    {
        return new PostModel()
        {
            Id = (int)dataRecord["Id"],
            Body = dataRecord["Body"].ToString(),
            Title = dataRecord["Title"].ToString(),
            Date = (DateTime)dataRecord["Date"],
            AuthorID = (int)dataRecord["AuthorID"],
            CategorieId = (int)dataRecord["CategorieId"]
        };
    }



    public override int Insert(PostModel entity)
    {
        Command command = new Command($"insert into {TableName} (Body,Title,Date,AuthorID,CategorieId) " +
                                      $"output inserted.id " +
                                      $"values(@Body,@Title,@Date,@AuthorID,@CategorieId)");
        command.AddParameter("Body", entity.Body);
        command.AddParameter("Title", entity.Title);
        command.AddParameter("Date", entity.Date);
        command.AddParameter("AuthorID", entity.AuthorID);
        command.AddParameter("CategorieId", entity.CategorieId);

        return (int)Connection.ExecuteScalar(command);
    }

    public IEnumerable<PostModel> GetByCategoryId(int id)
    {
        Command command = new Command($"select * from {TableName} where CategorieId = @id");
        command.AddParameter("id", id);
        return Connection.ExecuteReader(command, Convert);
    }
```

So I would like join but the problem is that the data I will receive will no longer be a PostModel type object so how do I do it?

Thank you in advance!

Edit : 
Here is my BaseRepository class 
I also created a toolbox for ADO but I do not think that was useful that I post it

```
 public abstract class BaseRepository<TKey, TEntity> : IRepository<TKey, TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity<TKey>
{
    private string tableName;
    private Connection connection;
    private string connectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-QTO99IS;Database=ForumYoutube;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    protected Connection Connection
    {
        get { return connection; }
    }

    protected string TableName { get { return tableName; } }

    public BaseRepository(string tableName)
    {
        this.tableName = $"[{tableName}]";
        connection = new Connection(connectionString);
    }

    public TEntity Get(TKey id)
    {
        Command command = new Command($"select * from {tableName} where id = @id");
        command.AddParameter("id", id);
        return connection.ExecuteReader(command, Convert).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        Command command = new Command($"select * from {tableName}");
        return connection.ExecuteReader(command, Convert);
    }

    public bool Delete(TKey id)
    {
        Command command = new Command($"delete * from {tableName} where id = @id");
        command.AddParameter("id", id);
        return connection.ExecuteNonQuery(command) == 1;
    }
    public abstract TEntity Convert(IDataRecord dataRecord);

    public abstract bool Update(TEntity entity);

    public abstract TKey Insert(TEntity entity);
}
```

Comment: you can use generic could you show us part of code from `BaseRepository`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I added the class in the post

Comment: No way around it easy. Either you use something gross like *dynamic* for this or create concrete class. This will lead to DTO code duplicates, but usually it's worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer eocron!

In fact I thought I would make an object that contains the information I need and make a method in PostRepository like GetPostAndLastUserAnswer () and send me a list of that object.

What do you think ?